# Hibernate unable to update object: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate

I'm getting error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

when I tried to updated object in SQL server (Microsoft).

I can see that query looks like:

```
update
    TABLE
set
    ORDER_NUMBER=?,
where
    IDENTIFIER=?
```

What I think is problem with IDENTIFIER. It's primary key but it' is varchar, so in model class is defined as String.

In my model file it's look like:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "IDENTIFIER", nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(17)")
private String identifier;
```

I'm only updating that table, other application adds records there.

Thanks for advice.

**UPDATE**

What I can see this is not connected with Hibernate.
I can't update that even using SQL Console.
I'm getting same error

Comment: Are you sure it's not that you are passing a character value to ORDER_NUMBER and it's an integer?

Comment: @JacobH ORDER_NUMBER is defined in DB as VARCHAR(255), so yes I'm sure about that

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't specified a generation strategy for the @Id column, it will default to GenerationType.AUTO - this uses types int, long or short.

Your identifier attribute is a String and the conversion to one of those numeric types is failing.

One option would be to change your identifier attribute to be of type long, short or int.

This article gives a good overview of different identifiers for Hibernate. You could use a Custom Generator if you're IDENTIFIER field is particularly complex: http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers

Comment: I'm unable to do that, I don't maintenance that DB and strange is that, I'm not inserting to that DB but only updating record that already is persisted in DB

Comment: Can you see any of the existing data? Are the values in the IDENTIFIER field currently set to numeric values or strings?

Comment: I'm selecting some records based on IDENTIFIER column, next I'm change ORDER_NUMBER column and next I'm trying to UPDATE that object in DB. So I don't change IDENTIFIER value, and that values cannot be cast to Numeric because they are plain Strings like 'ABCD'

Answer (score 0):

ok, I know what was wrong. On that table there was additional procedure that trigger on Update and there was an error that result with

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.